# What is the best way to mock a database in flutter (SQFlite)?

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I need to mock my database for unit testing. I've tried mockito, however, it enforced so much stubbing (required stubs for every single internal function) which takes too much time and I simply want to check if an toMap -> insert -> query -> fromMap works correctly.

What is the easiest way to mock a database in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

you can mock sqflite by using a real implementation with `sqflite_common_ffi` since it works on all desktop (MacOS, Linux, Windows) on the dart VM so also in flutter and dart unit tests:

More information here: https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite_common_ffi#unit-test-code

One solution is open a database in memory for each test so that you start with an empty database.

```dart
import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'package:sqflite_common/sqlite_api.dart';
import 'package:sqflite_common_ffi/sqflite_ffi.dart';

void main() {
  // Init ffi loader if needed.
  sqfliteFfiInit();
  test('simple sqflite example', () async {
    var db = await databaseFactoryFfi.openDatabase(inMemoryDatabasePath);
    expect(await db.getVersion(), 0);
    await db.close();
  });
}
```